# Extract datetime value where time is minimal R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, posixct

I am using the suncalc package to generate sunlight times for a set of dates with lat/lon coordinates.  Here is some sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)
library(lubridate)
library(suncalc)

data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17975, 18044, 18231, 18172, 
18169), class = "Date"), lat = c(40.7128, 41.8781, 34.0522, 25.7617, 
39.9526), lon = c(-74.006, -87.6298, -118.2437, -80.1918, -75.1652
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

data
        date     lat       lon
1 2019-03-20 40.7128  -74.0060
2 2019-05-28 41.8781  -87.6298
3 2019-12-01 34.0522 -118.2437
4 2019-10-03 25.7617  -80.1918
5 2019-09-30 39.9526  -75.1652
```

From there, it's fairly straightforward to generate, say, times of sunrise and sunset for each day and for a given time zone:

```
data %>% 
  getSunlightTimes(data = ., keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"), tz = "America/Los_Angeles")

        date     lat       lon             sunrise              sunset
1 2019-03-20 40.7128  -74.0060 2019-03-20 04:01:11 2019-03-20 16:08:32
2 2019-05-28 41.8781  -87.6298 2019-05-28 03:21:36 2019-05-28 18:16:52
3 2019-12-01 34.0522 -118.2437 2019-12-01 06:41:42 2019-12-01 16:45:14
4 2019-10-03 25.7617  -80.1918 2019-10-03 04:14:55 2019-10-03 16:07:12
5 2019-09-30 39.9526  -75.1652 2019-09-30 03:56:49 2019-09-30 15:47:06
```

The resulting sunrise and sunset values are of class POSIXct, representing both date and time info together.  From here, what I want to do is extract the sunrise value where the time is minimal regardless of the date.  Thus, the value I'd want to extract in this case is the data in row 2 of the sunrise column.  The result should have the date and time information intact, but the value is chosen based on the time criteria rather than the date.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice` after converting to `ITime`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   getSunlightTimes(data = ., keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"),
        tz = "America/Los_Angeles") %>% 
   slice(which.min(as.ITime(sunrise)))
# date     lat      lon             sunrise              sunset
#1 2019-05-28 41.8781 -87.6298 2019-05-28 03:21:36 2019-05-28 18:16:52
```

---

Or using `base R`, we can do this more easily if we `format`, change the 'Date' part to a common date and use `which.min`

```
data[with(data, which.min(as.POSIXct(format(sunrise, "2020-01-01 %H:%M:%S")))),]
#        date     lat      lon             sunrise              sunset
#2 2019-05-28 41.8781 -87.6298 2019-05-28 03:21:36 2019-05-28 18:16:52
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
data$time_only <- strftime(df$sunrise, format="%H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
data[as.character(data$time_only) == min(data$time_only), -ncol(data)]
```

**Output**

```
# date     lat      lon             sunrise              sunset
# 2019-05-28 41.8781 -87.6298 2019-05-28 03:21:36 2019-05-28 18:16:52
```